# How to get started with soap ui

Tags: soapui

Hi i am new to web services and looking for someone who can help me in working with some simple example to understand testing webservices using SOAPui tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

open SoapUI

- new project - name it whatever you want, and map to a WSDL
- I found a repository of SOAP webservices at [www.service-repository.com](http://www.service-repository.comhttp://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl), try this WSDL: http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl
- Click OK, and the app will load a number of requests you can run.
- open one of these requests, and fill in the XML blanks/question-marks.
- on the top left there's a green submit button - that will send your request, and return an XML.

Comment: who will test webservicses developer or a tester?

Comment: That would depend on how much the tester knows, and what it is you're trying to test. If all you want is to see a response, a tester can be easily guided. If you're checking content - you might want the developer to test it, or teach the tester more about WS

Answer (score 0):

You can find each of the steps on using SoapUI tool and very basic example of creating a SOAP web service in the below mentioned URL.

http://analogyofcodes.blogspot.com/

I hope this might help you to ramp-up with SoapUI tool.